# c# user input array for integer to look for specific number

Tags: c#, arrays, user-input

Im new to programming i use c# to solve some problem but i have problem when user input two integer no in same-line and i want to look for zero and remove it from each no  i think by replacing with the next array cell i should convert integer to string again but i cant do it please help me

```
 string[] arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        string a = arr[0];
        string b = arr[1];
        int[] m = new int[1];
        int[] n = new int[1];



        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {

            if (a[i] == 0 && a[a.Length - 1] != 0)
            {
                for (int j = i; j < a.Length; j++)
                {
                    //****m[i] = int.Parse(a[i]); the error here cant convert from char to string ??
                 //   a[i] = a[i + 1];**\\ Error    CS0200  Property or indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only**
```

Comment: Not related to your question but the code would be easier to follow with meaningful variable names, there are some tips here https://dzone.com/articles/naming-conventions-from-uncle-bobs-clean-code-phil

Comment: Give some inputs along with expected outputs, it'd go a long way in helping people understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to convert the char into an ASCII value, then you would have to use the static method of `Char` called `GetNumericValue`.

Information on `GetNumericValue` can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: thanks for commenti want to search for zero in long number and remove it by shifting the next digit to zero location but the problem i cant search in long number if i dont convert it to string when i convert to string i cant make this relation (a[i]=a[i+1]) so i tried again by define another int array M but also doesn't work because this integer and the array of a is string how can i solve it